# How to fix footer at the bottom of responsive page?

Tags: css

I have a responsive page. I want to fix footer at the bottom of this page. I have searched a lot and find many working solutions. However, all of them are failed when it comes to the responsive page. The problem is that when I set position for footer to be fixed, once I reduce the screen size the footer stay in its place and gets covered by contents. I set the z-index to make it on the outer layer. However. it stays in the middle of the screen while the hight gets bigger and contents go below it. I know the page layout I made does not looks right but i do not know what to change.Please look at the code and advice me what to change.
Note:
1- I used javascript to make the margin-top change with screen size
2- I used Django for back end and extends base page to this form page

this is the base page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {% static 'towns/style/bootstrap_3.3.7_dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'towns/style/bootstrap_3.3.7_dist/css/bootstrap_theme.min.css' %}">
    <!-- to add future links when it is needed -->
    {% block links %}
    {% endblock %}

    <!-- main bar links -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'towns/style/list_page/header.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'towns/style/list_page/css/font_awesome.min.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'towns/style/base/base.css' %}">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aref+Ruqaa|Reem+Kufi" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container_sl">
        <div class="main">
            <header class="global-header">
                <div class="main-container">
                    <div>
                      <a class="header-logo" style="text-decoration:none;" name="" href="#"> </a>
                    </div>

                    <nav class="main-search-cat">

                            <ul class="breadcrumbs" id="menu">

                                <!-- links to the main pages -->
                                <span>
                                    <li class="crumb section">
                                        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/towns/{{post_city}}">  </a>
                                    </li>

                                </span>


                            </ul>

                    </nav>

                    <!-- *********************************** -->
                    <!-- start of user links -->
                    <!-- *********************************** -->
                    <div id = "userlinks">
                        <div id="nav">
                            <ul >
                                <li>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div> 
            </header>
            <section class="m-container">
                <div class="ar-contns">
                    {% block content%}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>  
            </section>

        </div>

    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
            <div class="footer-wr">
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </footer>

<!-- footer container end -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src=" {% static 'towns/javascript/jquery_3.1.1.min.js' %}">
    </script>



    <!-- adjust m-container top margin for small screen -->
    <script>

        // to fix the s-container top margin for small screen
        function fixSecondTop() {
                $(".m-container").css({
                "margin-top": $(".main-container").outerHeight()+ 50
                });
        }

        fixSecondTop();

        $(window).resize(function () {fixSecondTop();});



        // to fix the footer top margin for small screen
        function fixFooterTop() {
                $(".footer").css({
                "margin-top": $(".main-container").outerHeight() + 20
                });
        }

        fixFooterTop();

        $(window).resize(function () {fixFooterTop();});


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the  form page:

```
{% extends "towns/salehslist/base.html" %}
{% block links %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 
'towns/style/complains/complains_form.css' %}">
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
<center class='center'>
    <div>
        <form>
            <h2 class="salehslist" id="SL_text"> 
                <center>  </center> 
            </h2>



            <div >
                <div>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {% if form.name %}
                                {% if form.name.errors%}
                                {{form.name.errors}}
                                {% elif form.non_field_errors%}
                                {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                                {% endif %}
                            {%endif%}
                </div>
            </div>

                    <div >
                                {{form.name}}

                    </div>
                    <label >

                                {{form.name.label_tag}}

                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div >
                <button type="submit"   > submit </button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</center>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is the css for base page

```
/* beginning of header styling*/
body{
margin-top:0;
margin-left:0;
}
.main-container{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;

background-color:#eeeeee;   
z-index: 10;
display:block;
width:100%;
height:50px;
box-sizing:border-box;
overflow: hidden;
border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.header-logo {
-webkit-border-radius: 2em;
-moz-border-radius: 2em;
border-radius: 2em;
background-color: #fff;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
float: left;
line-height: 1.5;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 1em;
padding-top:0px;
text-decoration:none;
font-family: 'Aref Ruqaa', serif;
font-size: 15px;
color: #304ffe  ;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
position:relative;
left:20px;
top:5px;

}

.main-search-cat{
float: left;
font-size: .9375em;
min-height: 1.3em;
position: relative;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 15px;
}
 /*setting anchor color*/
a {
color: #304ffe;
}
a:visited {
color: #304ffe;
}
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
ul#menu li {
display:inline;
}

.breadcrumbs-form{
position:relative;
left:50px;
margin-bottom: 0px !important;
margin-top: 0px !important;
min-height: auto !important;
padding-bottom: 10px !important;
padding-top: 10px !important;
width: auto;
float: left;  
}

/* userlinks */

#userlinks{
float:right;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
#userlinks #nav{
padding-top: 15px;
padding-right: 30px
}
#userlinks #nav li{
float:right;
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;
padding-right: 10px;
}

#userlinks #nav li a{
color: #304ffe;;
}

.bar{
color:#9e9e9e;
float:right;
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;
padding-right: 10px; 
}

.favorites{
background-color: #ffc;
}
.banished{
background-color: #ffccbc;
}
.glyphicon-star{
color:#ffab00;
padding-right: 5px;
}

.glyphicon-trash{
color:#bf360c;
padding-right: 5px;  
background-color: #ffccbc;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;

}

/* media settings for small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px){
.main-container{
    height:auto;
}
ul#menu li {
    display: block;
}  

#userlinks #nav li{
    display:block; 
    clear:both;   
}
#userlinks #nav{
    padding-right: 5px 
}
.bar{
    display:none;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px){
.main-container{
height:auto;
padding-bottom: 5px;
clear:both;
}
#userlinks{
float:left;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
 #userlinks #nav li{
float:left;
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;
padding-left:110px;
clear:both;
}
}
/* end of header styling*/


/* beginning of footer styling*/


.container_sl{
min-height: 100vh;
}

.main{
/*overflow:auto;*/
padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.m-container{

}

.ar-contns{
float: right;
font-size: 1.5em;
direction: rtl;
}
/*m container (the container contains contents) */


/*footer styling*/
.footer{
background-color: #000;
position: relative;
height:50px;
margin-top: -50px;

width:100%;
float:right;
box-sizing:border-box;
background-color: #eee;
border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
clear: both;
}

.footer-wr li {
position: relative;
list-style: none;
left:30%;
padding-left:10px;
top:7px;
display:inline;
float:left;
font-size: 1em;     
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}

/* to adjust horizontal line */
hr {
color: #ccc;
background: #ccc;
height: 2px;
border: 0;
}

/*responsive screen*/

/*showing the side-nav for small screen*/
@media screen and (max-width:992px){

/*footer setting*/
.footer{
    height:auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right:40%;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer-wr li{
    float:none;
    display:list-item;
}

}

/* end of footer styling */
```

Here is the css for form page

```
body{
margin-top:0;
margin-left:0;
}
.salehslist {
font-family: 'Aref Ruqaa', serif;
font-size: 60px;
text-decoration:none;
color: #304ffe  ;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
padding-bottom: 50px;
text-decoration:none;
}
.center{
height:;
}
```

I want to make the footer always stay at the bottom of the page regardless of the screen size

Comment: Can you please create a snippet? So someone has quickly fixed your issue. Thank you.

Comment: I think your problem is not within the footer but within `.main-container` being a position absolute. Have you tried making that position relative?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make footer with dynamic height is flex parent element(can be body) and column direction for all flex items (including footer). Then use flex grow for footer item to fill bottom space. This solution require parent element to be atleast 100% vh.

Comment: Your answer is valid, but your explanation is quite hard. if I look at Saleh CSS I'm guessing you should simplify it or use code examples.

Comment: Answered on mobile and his stylesheet is quite large so I only pointed direction. Feel free to answer with example.

Answer (score 0):

when the content in the body is too small or not enough the footer continues to change positions when resizing the window into different screen sizes. However you should try to put enough content in the body to help pushing the footer down at the very bottom

```
footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; }
```

Instead of putting 'position: absolute' you can replace with 'position: fixed' if you want the footer to stick on the bottom part any time.